# Get a specific response header (e.g., Content-Disposition) in Angular from an ASP.NET Web API 2 response for a cross-origin http.get request

Tags: c#, angular, cors, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I cannot get a specific header (`Content-Disposition`) when I'm accessing it via an Angular service. CORS is enabled and the Angular HTTPClient is set to retrieve ALL headers.

**Startup.cs**

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            ConfigureOAuth(app, config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
 }
```

**fileController.cs**

```
[Route("file/{idFile}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(string idFile)
        {
            string file;
            byte[] file;

            document = fileService.GetFile(idDFile, out fileName);

            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(file)
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = nomeFile
                };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            return result;
        }
```

**fileService.ts**

```
getFile(fileId: number): Observable<Response> {
        const url = `${urlBackEnd}/file/${fileId}`;
        return this.http.get(url, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' })
          .map(res => {;
            console.log(res.headers.keys()); // There's no CONTENT-DISPOSITION
            saveAs(<Blob>res.body);
            return res.body;
          })
          .catch(e => this.handleErrors(e));
}
```

Here's the header console.log:

```
[
  "content-type",
  "cache-control"
]
```

What am I missing? I just want to get the `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: The server you’re sending the cross-origin request to must include na Access-Control-Expose-Headers header in the response, with Content-Disposition in its value. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020385/fetch-api-not-returning-the-location-header/39021128#39021128

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker, i tried doing that but still, i cannot get that header. https://i.imgur.com/NemwLRb.png `result.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");`

Comment: I think browsers don’t yet support the `*` wildcard value for the Access-Control-Expose-Headers. Try instead explicitly listing Content-Disposition in the value.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58601675/angular-how-to-get-headers-value-in-the-canactive-function/58602196#58602196

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the `fileController.cs` file, along with setting the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` response headers, you need to set [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers):

```
result.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
```

Note that while the Fetch spec does actually allow "`*`" as the value of `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` (though that’s not very clear from reading the current spec text…) — browsers don’t yet conform to the spec on that; so instead you should explicitly list all response header names the browser should expose to your frontend JavaScript code — except for `Cache-Control`, `Content-Language`, `Content-Type`, `Expires`, `Last-Modified`, and `Pragma`, which are always exposed. For any response headers other than those six and the ones you explicitly list in the value of the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header, browsers block frontend code from accessing them.

Comment: Don't know if it matters too much -- I had to use the hyphenated name:  `Content-Disposition`  ::  `result.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");`

Comment: @MarkHeadley Yeah it does make a difference. So I edited the answer to correct that — thanks for catching that so that I could fix it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adjusting my CORS rule defined in the server (ASP.NET Core 8) to look like this

```
var corsPolicy = new CorsPolicyBuilder()
    .WithOrigins(builder.Configuration["FrontendUrl"])
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials()
    .WithExposedHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentDisposition)
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("wasm", corsPolicy));
```

When exposing the "Content-Disposition", you can also read it in your client.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
 httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
 httpServletResponse.setHeader(Content-Disposition,getFileName());
```

This solution working for me.

Comment: Is this a better solution than the accepted answer 2 years prior, which explains what and why headers are being set?