# Response headers in Dart BrowserClient

Tags: dart, dart-html

I have a code where I POST a request and the response code is 201 created with "Location": "URL" header of the new created resource.

```
final Response response = await _http.post(getUri(_url), body: plan);
return _getPlan(response.headers['location']);
```

Where `_http` is a BrowserClient from the package `http-0.12.0+1`. But the `response.headers['Location']` is empty. The `headers` array itself contains only one element `Content-Type`.
In Chrome developers tools I see all response headers including `Location`. 
What am I doing wrong? How can I access the response headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Günter Zöchbauer for pointing me for the answer. As described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39021128/1444083 the missing header is [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) (not [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)).

As I use Dart Aqueduct on the server side I had to add this line to the Channel prepare() method

```
class MyAppChannel extends ApplicationChannel {
  @override
  Future prepare() async {
    // ... some code
    CORSPolicy.defaultPolicy.exposedResponseHeaders.add('location');
  }
}
```

so the responses now contain `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: location`

Answer (score 2):

I assume the response misses the header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:location
```

and therefore the browser prevents JavaScript (Dart) accessing the header (CORS).

To make the header available to JavaScript (Dart) you need to change the server to include above header in responses.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36281935/217408

Comment: Thank you for a hint. Your answer directed me to the right header. Correct header to be added is ``Access-Control-Expose-Headers`` (not ``Access-Control-Allow-Headers``). See my answer bellow.