# Node.js PayUMoney Integration - response.headers.location is undefined

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, payumoney

Tried 2 Node.js packages:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/payumoney_nodejs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/payumoney-node

Debugging on localhost.
Debugged in the `index.js` file under the `node_modules` in each package.

```
params {
  key: 'x1FanfbP',
  salt: 'Vs2GrDyaMQ',
  service_provider: 'payu_paisa',
  hash: '65f75ced566e2d76dbc6153a277c25f591fc3c0a00a8f51a0699f609d5cbbc94dc7acd5d3be5fe0c0a855c4c6dc7faef49d8b6a1d77dd09398058f800bab068d',
  firstname: '',
  lastname: '',
  email: 'xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx',
  phone: XXXXXXXXXX,
  amount: '100',
  productinfo: '',
  txnid: '5b51d253-5d6e-4512-951a-cd6d05bf9e6b',
  surl: 'http://localhost:3000/member/contribution/success',
  furl: 'http://localhost:3000/member/contribution/failure'
}

request.post(this.payUmoneyURL, form: params, headers: this.headers }, 
    function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            var result = response.headers.location;
            callback(error, result);
        }
});


request.post(payment_url[this.mode] + API.makePayment, { form: params, headers: this.headers }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            var result = response.headers.location;
            callback(error, result);
        }
});
```

Response of response.headers:

```
response.headers {
    date: 'Fri, 28 Jun 2019 12:06:35 GMT',
    server: 'Apache',
    'x-powered-by': 'PHP/7.2.14',
    p3p: 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"',
    'set-cookie': [ 'PHPSESSID=naopga57qf58vl0hdfj5krq4n5; path=/; domain=.payu.in' ],
    expires: 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT',
    'cache-control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate',
    pragma: 'no-cache',
    vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
    'content-length': '3129',
    connection: 'close',
    'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
}
```

The above does not have `location` key like `response.headers.location`

Can someone help to know why `location` is not returned?
Is it because of development on local machine? If yes, then how to test it on localhost?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why do you need a location?

Comment: In the package urls provided in the question says the API is suppose to return a URL which needs to be sent to the UI (Angular in my case) and then redirect to that URL.

Comment: In request body have you set surl and furl as per the documentation?

Comment: @user269867 Yes, have set those values. Give me some time, will provide the `requestBody` data sent to the `payUMoney.pay()` and `payumoney.makePayment()` call.

Comment: also if you can share the output of  ```console.log(response)```

Comment: @user269867 I have updated the question with `params` value that is sent to the API call. The log of `response` key is very big and so I have only provided the value of `response.headers`.

Comment: It say "You will get a link in response to redirect to payUMoney"  , you are checking in headers but it might be in the response itself. refer article - https://medium.com/@swapnilnakhate/payumoney-payment-gateway-integration-with-nodejs-f715e5fc25a

Comment: I have searched in the `response` but there is no such key as `location`.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020385/fetch-api-not-returning-the-location-header

Comment: @KunalDethe do you see "payulink" in response?

Comment: @user269867 Yes, its working now. The issue was with the missing parameters data. Have mentioned it in detail in the answer below. Thank you for all the replies. Helped to look around the entire `response` object searching for the error.

Comment: glad it worked !may be you can upvote the comment

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a very silly mistake made but didn't know the area as where to look for the error in the `response` key before.

After going through the entire `response` object found that there is a `body` key sent at the very end of the `response` object which has `HTML` string. This HTML specifies if any error has occurred and what exactly it is.

In my case it were the missing mandatory fields:

```
Error Reason
One or more mandatory parameters are missing in the transaction request.

Corrective Action
Please ensure that you send all mandatory parameters in the transaction request to PayU.

Mandatory parameters which must be sent in the transaction are: 
key, txnid, amount, productinfo, firstname, email, phone, surl, furl, hash.

The parameters which you have actually sent in the transaction are: 
key, txnid, amount, surl, hash, email, phone.

Mandatory parameter missing from your transaction request are: 
productinfo, firstname.

Please re-initiate the transaction with all the mandatory parameters.
```

After passing data for the missing parameters, received the `url` in the `response.headers.location` key as expected.

Integration is working as expected now.